# What does this mean (the treble clef part) and how to play it?

Tags: piano, notation, tremolo

[image]

This is the accompaniment piece for a clarinet solo and I do not know how to play this measure.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like a tremolo. It is played as a oscillation between the top two notes (I'm guessing a A and a D) and the lower note (I'm guessing an F). The dotted half-note (written on each stem) indicates either 3 quarter-note beats or 6 eighth-note beats (or the equivalent); the 6 eighth notes in the other staff probably mean the latter. The three lines connecting the upper notes mean to (approximately) play the oscillation as thirty-second notes. On a keyboard (which this looks like it's from) this gives a shimmering effect to the chords. It's a bit like a trill but with larger intervals and more notes.

Comment: Good answer, but the time is almost certainly 6/8, which means two beats of dotted minims/half-notes.

Answer (score 1):

It's a tremolo, which for a pianist means to alternate very rapidly between the two notes/chords.  [Here's a video that shows you how to do it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I-JFfp7E3uw).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I could not leave it.

those answers are usually called `community wiki` aren't they?

[image]

thanks to @BrianChandler
and @AlexanderWoo

Comment: This is just not what is indicated: the tremolo should go between the two notes/chords indicated by the notes with a duration of the bar: i.e. DA - F - DA - F and so on.

Comment: No - this is wrong - the A and D are played simultaneously, alternating with the F being played by itself.

Comment: As of this comment, what is notated here is 32nd notes, not tremolo.

Comment: @ToddWilcox, yes, but this is how it looks like when you unfold the example of the OP.